# Restrict jqGrid columns eligible for searching?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, navigation, find

Is there a way you can restrict which grid columns are eligible for searching on using the jqGrid search navigation bar feature?

In other words, specify that only 3 of your 5 columns will appear in the field list on the Find bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [search configuration docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config), you can use the `search` colModel option to indicate whether a field can be eligible for searching:

> search - boolean - Determines if the field can be searched.

Comment: Thanks, should have seen that!